# Crypt::OpenPGP does not support .kbx ring format?

Tags: perl, openpgp

I've been trying to get Crypt::OpenPGP  to work with a new pubring.kbx file but it fails with 'No known recipients for encryption'.

If I export the keys in my pubring.kbx file to a pubring.gpg file then I can get the process to work successfully.

Is there any way to get Crypt::OpenPGP to work with new .kbx files?

Alternatively, what PGP implementation would you recommend for Perl scripts that need to be Operating System agnostic (specifically work on Windows, Linux, FreeBSD) in 2022?

Thanks